# Why did my cloud run eventarc trigger lose it's topic subscription?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I have a cloud run service deployed, with an eventarc trigger which creates a pubsub topic behind the scenes, to which the trigger is subscribed.

Recently to my horror I noticed the trigger was not being invoked anymore.  Looking further I noticed there were 0 subscriptions to the pubsub topic.  I went to the cloud run service console and the trigger still existed, so why no subscription to the topic?

I have redeployed the service multiple times before, and the subscription has never disappeared like this.  Deleting and re-creating the trigger brought back the subscription, however now I lost all my messages.  :-(

Can anyone explain how this could happen, and if it does happen again, how I can re-enable the subscription without re-creating the trigger and thus losing all my pubsub messages?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you check in the activity log to view what/who has deleted the subscription?

Comment: I just checked, and there is no subscription deletion in the logs!  One thing that stands out is the last time my service was triggered by the subscription was `2021-05-02T16:31:50.962698549Z` and the next activity in the audit log was `2021-05-05T14:39:58.622940Z` and it was `AssignResourceToBillingAccount` action.  After that the service was never triggered again.

Answer (score 2):

Pub/Sub subscriptions created by Eventarc triggers should definitely not expire. If you see this again, please open a bug with details: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: Google Support let me know that a subscription without activity will expire by default after 31.  This was my issue, but since there is no way to configure expiration when creating an Eventarc trigger from within the cloud run console, I'd consider this a bug and will let support know.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/creating-triggers. 

This doc page says "By default, Pub/Sub subscriptions created for Eventarc persist regardless of activity and do not expire. To change the inactivity duration, see Managing subscriptions."

Comment: It appears that went into effect on May 3rd, this was indeed my issue

Answer (score 0):

I received this message from the engineering team:

"As of May 3rd, pubsub subscriptions created by creating an Eventarc trigger are set to never expire. Previously, they had a default expiration of 30 days of inactivity.

It sounds like what the customer is experiencing is consistent with that. What happened was there were 30 days of inactivity and the subscription expired.

The workaround at the moment would be to create a new trigger."